# qt: an internal error occurced in the compiler

Tags: c++, string, qt, translate

I am currently writing an Disassembler, now I want to create new strings, like that:

```
// Disassembler Sourcefile

// better known as DisAsm
#include "disassembler.h"

#include <QString>

Disassembler::Disassembler()
{
    QString *_protos = new QString[] { "NOP",
        "LD BC,d16",
        "LD (BC),A",
        "INC BC",
        "INC B",
        "DEC B",
        "LD B,d8",
        "RLCA",
        "LD (a16),SP",
        "ADD HL,BC",
        "LD A,(BC)",
        "DEC BC",
        "INC C",
        "DEC C",
        "LD C,d8",
        "RRCA",
        "STOP 0",
        "LD DE,d16",
        "LD (DE),A",
        "INC DE",
        "INC D",
        "DEC D",
        "LD D,d8",
        "RLA",
        "JR r8",
        "ADD HL,DE",
        "LD A,(DE)",
        "DEC DE",
        "INC E",
        "DEC E",
        "LD E,d8",
        "RRA",
        "JR NZ,r8",
        "LD HL,d16",
        "LD (HL+),A",
        "INC HL",
        "INC H",
        "DEC H",
        "LD H,d8",
        "DAA",
        "JR Z,r8",
        "ADD HL,HL",
        "LD A,(HL+)",
        "DEC HL",
        "INC L",
        "DEC L",
        "LD L,d8",
        "CPL",
        "JR NC,r8",
        "LD SP,d16",
        "LD (HL-),A",
        "INC SP",
        "INC (HL)",
        "DEC (HL)",
        "LD (HL),d8",
        "SCF",
        "JR C,r8",
        "ADD HL,SP",
        "LD A,(HL-)",
        "DEC SP",
        "INC A",
        "DEC A",
        "LD A,d8",
        "CCF",
        "LD B,B",
        "LD B,C",
        "LD B,D",
        "LD B,E",
        "LD B,H",
        "LD B,L",
        "LD B,(HL)",
        "LD B,A",
        "LD C,B",
        "LD C,C",
        "LD C,D",
        "LD C,E",
        "LD C,H",
        "LD C,L",
        "LD C,(HL)",
        "LD C,A",
        "LD D,B",
        "LD D,C",
        "LD D,D",
        "LD D,E",
        "LD D,H",
        "LD D,L",
        "LD D,(HL)",
        "LD D,A",
        "LD E,B",
        "LD E,C",
        "LD E,D",
        "LD E,E",
        "LD E,H",
        "LD E,L",
        "LD E,(HL)",
        "LD E,A",
        "LD H,B",
        "LD H,C",
        "LD H,D",
        "LD H,E",
        "LD H,H",
        "LD H,L",
        "LD H,(HL)",
        "LD H,A",
        "LD L,B",
        "LD L,C",
        "LD L,D",
        "LD L,E",
        "LD L,H",
        "LD L,L",
        "LD L,(HL)",
        "LD L,A",
        "LD (HL),B",
        "LD (HL),C",
        "LD (HL),D",
        "LD (HL),E",
        "LD (HL),H",
        "LD (HL),L",
        "HALT",
        "LD (HL),A",
        "LD A,B",
        "LD A,C",
        "LD A,D",
        "LD A,E",
        "LD A,H",
        "LD A,L",
        "LD A,(HL)",
        "LD A,A",
        "ADD A,B",
        "ADD A,C",
        "ADD A,D",
        "ADD A,E",
        "ADD A,H",
        "ADD A,L",
        "ADD A,(HL)",
        "ADD A,A",
        "ADC A,B",
        "ADC A,C",
        "ADC A,D",
        "ADC A,E",
        "ADC A,H",
        "ADC A,L",
        "ADC A,(HL)",
        "ADC A,A",
        "SUB B",
        "SUB C",
        "SUB D",
        "SUB E",
        "SUB H",
        "SUB L",
        "SUB (HL)",
        "SUB A",
        "SBC A,B",
        "SBC A,C",
        "SBC A,D",
        "SBC A,E",
        "SBC A,H",
        "SBC A,L",
        "SBC A,(HL)",
        "SBC A,A",
        "AND B",
        "AND C",
        "AND D",
        "AND E",
        "AND H",
        "AND L",
        "AND (HL)",
        "AND A",
        "XOR B",
        "XOR C",
        "XOR D",
        "XOR E",
        "XOR H",
        "XOR L",
        "XOR (HL)",
        "XOR A",
        "OR B",
        "OR C",
        "OR D",
        "OR E",
        "OR H",
        "OR L",
        "OR (HL)",
        "OR A",
        "CP B",
        "CP C",
        "CP D",
        "CP E",
        "CP H",
        "CP L",
        "CP (HL)",
        "CP A",
        "RET NZ",
        "POP BC",
        "JP NZ,a16",
        "JP a16",
        "CALL NZ,a16",
        "PUSH BC",
        "ADD A,d8",
        "RST 00H",
        "RET Z",
        "RET",
        "JP Z,a16",
        "PREFIX CB",
        "CALL Z,a16",
        "CALL a16",
        "ADC A,d8",
        "RST 08H",
        "RET NC",
        "POP DE",
        "JP NC,a16",
        "???",
        "CALL NC,a16",
        "PUSH DE",
        "SUB d8",
        "RST 10H",
        "RET C",
        "RETI",
        "JP C,a16",
        "???",
        "CALL C,a16",
        "???",
        "SBC A,d8",
        "RST 18H",
        "LDH (a8),A",
        "POP HL",
        "LD (C),A",
        "???",
        "???",
        "PUSH HL",
        "AND d8",
        "RST 20H",
        "ADD SP,r8",
        "JP HL",
        "LD (a16),A",
        "???",
        "???",
        "???",
        "XOR d8",
        "RST 28H",
        "LDH A,(a8)",
        "POP AF",
        "LD A,(C)",
        "DI",
        "???",
        "PUSH AF",
        "OR d8",
        "RST 30H",
        "LD HL,SP+r8",
        "LD SP,HL",
        "LD A,(a16)",
        "EI",
        "???",
        "???",
        "CP d8",
        "RST 38H" };
}
```

But now I get an error in the last line/line 256 (means the last line of the complete file).

***C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\GB Emulator\gbx00\disassembler.cpp:265: Error: C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.***

I have tried to replace the "};" with only an "}" but this didn't works to. How can I fix this?

NOTE: I'll try to translate an C# code into C++/Qt.

Comment: can you clarify your post? First point the line 265. Second why is c# relevant?

Comment: @UmNyobe Because I translate an C# code into C++ to use it.

Comment: `new QString[]` returns a `QString[] *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create an array of `QString`s it should be:

```
QString _protos[] = { "NOP",
                      "LD BC,d16",
                      "LD (BC),A",
                      ...
                      "RST 38H" };
```

instead.